# How to keep AS3 code simple

Tags: actionscript-3, events

This is my original pseudo code:

```
function1(); 

function1():void{
   //do something
   after mouseclick do function2
}
function2():void{
   //do something
   after animationfinish do function3
}
etc..
```

Can I get it into something like this?:

```
function1();
after mouseclick do function2()
after animationfinish do function3()
```

What is an easy way to get listeners on the top level?

Comment: You are talking about events. What can't you figure out ? We need more information on what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i good understand - You like to create functions chain .

I depends what You like to do , problem is in many possibilities.
For call few functions i use this class :
https://github.com/turbosqel/as3SupportLib/blob/master/as3SupportLib/src/turbosqel/utils/CountCall.as

You can also use deeper and more elastic way and add next callbacks to function :

```
var func:Function = function():void { // declare new function
   ... function body // your class actions
   for each(var call:Function in arguments.callee){ // get functions
      call(); // call function
   }
}

func["someFunction"] = someFunction; // add function as dynamic value
func["otherFunction"] = anotherFunctionToCall; // add another function

func(); // call function
```

Comment: That's what I wanted - functions chain! Thanx!

Comment: dont forget to remove references from function , it may cause leaks !

Comment: -1 since this is definitely not a solution to the OP. The functions in this solution are all executed synchronously, while the OP is about asynchronous daisy chaining

Comment: You should wake up and check what guy that create post write : "That's what I wanted" . So You think that answer is wrong , You must be kind of brainreader if You know better what author mean .
btw - first solution is for async functions  (CountCall.as)

Comment: Yeah, I know he wrote it's what he wanted. But it's not what he asked. If people come looking for an answer for the same kind of problem he described, they'll erroneously think it's a correct solution, while it's not. And while CountCall.as is a semi-asynchronous solution, it's not a real asynchronous queue. All it does is release the thread to execute all synchronous calls and immediately after that call the next function in queue. That's not the same as sequencing asynchronous calls. In other words, it doesn't solve the problem he described.

Comment: or You still dont understand what he need to know . I post answer , he approves and You trying to tell us that we are wrong ? He didnt event use words "async" or "event" , so how You may know what answer he expect ?

Comment: As I said, it might well be what he needed to know, but it's not what he asked, look at the code he provided: after mouseclick do function2 and in function2 after animation finished do function3.
Whether he knows that's async chaining or not is irrelevant.
When you ask a question, you don't know the answer that's why you ask a question. Apparently in his particular situation he was helped with your answer, good for you, good for him, but it's not an answer to the question he asked. It's not that hard to understand really.

Comment: I didn't vote -1 because I think your answer stinks, I just wanted to make clear that it's NOT an answer to the question posed, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, when function1 is called you want to `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function2);`

Are you using Actiosncript to animate or Keyframes?

I know with TweenMax you can add a function to call at the end of the tween. If using fl.Transtions.Tween you can listen for TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH and then call function3. I don't mess much with the timeline in Flash, since I feel more in control with coding it, but I know you can add code at the last frame of an animation to call function3.

If I am completely missing you question feel free to clarify what exactly you are seeking.